# c++ multiple inheritance casting

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, multiple-inheritance

I have a class:

```
class Base;
```

Also I have an interface

```
class Interface;
```

Next i'm creating a class

```
class Derived : public Base, public Interface;
```

If I have `Base *object = new Derived;`

How can i cast `object` to `Interface` ? (of course if i know than object is actually a derived class)

**EDIT:**

I've tried dynamic_cast and static_cast (not compiled).
So let me explain the problem a bit more:

I have:

```
class Object {...}

class ITouchResponder
{
public:
    virtual bool onTouchBegan(XTouch *touch) = 0;
    virtual void onTouchMoved(XTouch *touch) = 0;
    virtual void onTouchEnded(XTouch *touch) = 0;
};

class Ball : public Object, public ITouchResponder {...};

class TentacleSensor : public Object, public ITouchResponder {...}
```

Object have a `bool touchable_` property. If it's true then object is implementing ITouchResponder interface.

When I use it:

```
bool Level::onTouchBegan(XTouch *touch)
{
    ...
    ITouchResponder *responder = callback.nearestTouchable();
    if (responder)
    {
        if (responder->onTouchBegan(touch))
        {
            if (responder != ball_)
            {
                touch->setUserData(responder);
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}

ITouchResponder *QueryCallback::nearestTouchable() const
{
    for (list<Object*>::const_iterator it = objects_.begin(); it != objects_.end(); ++it)
    {
        if ( (*it)->isTouchable() ) return (*it)->asTouchResponder();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`asTouchResponder` is a method of `Object` :

```
    ITouchResponder * Object::asTouchResponder()
    {
        assert(touchable_);
        ITouchResponder *res = dynamic_cast<ITouchResponder*>(this);
        assert(res);
        return res;
    }
```

I have bad excess error in xcode.

But if i make `Object : public ITouchResponder` everything works fine. What am i doing wrong ?

Full object class:

```
class Object// : public ITouchResponder
{
public:
    struct Def
    {
        Def()
        {
            level = 0;
            world = 0;
            touchable = false;
            acceptsContacts = false;
            body = 0;
            node = 0;
        }
        Level *level;
        b2World *world;
        bool touchable;
        bool acceptsContacts;
        b2Body *body;
        XNode *node;
    };

    Object(const Def &def);
    virtual ~Object();

    virtual void update(float dt);
    bool isTouchable() const {return touchable_;}

    void addDependantObject(Object *object);
    void removeDependantObject(Object *object);

    virtual void objectWillBeRemoved(Object *object) {} //this function is automatically called to every dependant object when object is removed

    virtual XVec2 position() const;
    virtual float rotation() const;

    bool acceptsContacts() const {return acceptsContacts_;}

    b2Body *body() const {return body_;}

    Level *level() const {return level_;}
    b2World *world() const {return world_;}

    ITouchResponder *asTouchResponder();
    /*
    virtual bool onTouchBegan(XTouch *touch) {
        return false;
    }
    virtual void onTouchMoved(XTouch *touch)
    {
    }
    virtual void onTouchEnded(XTouch *touch) 
    {
    }*/

protected:
    Level *level_;
    b2World *world_;
    bool touchable_;
    bool acceptsContacts_;

    XNode *node_;
    b2Body *body_;

    list<Object*> dependantObjects_;
};
```

Comment: @vivek Don't use c casts in C++ code. There is a reason why the new syntax was introduced.

Comment: Ideally your pure virtual public interface could be used without the need for casting by calling methods on the interface pointer which are overriden in the derived class to do what is appropriate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If `Base` has `virtual` function (even be it `virtual` destructor), then:

```
Derived *pDerived = dynamic_cast<Derived *>(object);
```

Else, use

```
Derived *pDerived = static_cast<Derived *>(object);
```

---

Note that if `Base` doesn't have virtual function, then `dynamic_cast` will NOT compile. In `dynamic_cast`, **only** the source has to be a polymorphic object, in order to compile, and if the destination isn't polymorphic, then dynamic_cast will return null pointer:

Suppose `A` and `B` are polymorphic type, and `C` is non-polymorphic, then

```
A *pA = dynamic_cast<A*>(new C()); //error - source is not polymorphic!

A *pA = dynamic_cast<A*>(new B()); //ok
if ( pA == 0 )
      cout << "pA will be null if B is not derived from A" << endl;

C *pC = dynamic_cast<C*>(new B()); //ok
if ( pC == 0 )
       cout << "pC must be null" << endl;
```

Comment: It would be even better if you precised that `dynamic_cast` may return a null pointer, also since the main improvement of your post is precising limitations, it may be worth noting that crossing virtual inheritance relationship requires `dynamic_cast` (`static_cast` cannot).

Answer (score 8):

If you know for sure that the object is of `Derived` class - use `static_cast`, otherwise use `dynamic_cast` and check the result.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` will not compile if the base has not virtual function.

Comment: @Nawaz: True, but the compiler will emit a nice error message, yet static_cast will lead to UB if the object if of the wrong type and the compiler won't say a word. So here the key is not having virtual functions but knowing the type of the object.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `dynamic_cast<Derived*>(object)` for that, and if the cast succeeds you'll get a `Derived*` returned, else the cast will return NULL.  You use this type of cast if Base is a polymorphic type, ie. contains a virtual function, and if this is not the case, you can use a `static_cast<Derived*>` instead.

Your problem is that you have an `Object` class that does not inherit from your interface `ITouchResponder` and therefore your `dynamic_cast` from `Object` to your interface is invalid.  You can only do a dynamic_cast on classes that inherit from one another, that's the whole purpose of polymorphism, so like you suggested in your example, your `Object` class should inherit publicly from your interface.

Essentially, you're doing an upcast here, `ITouchResponder *res = dynamic_cast<ITouchResponder*>(this);` from Derived to Base Interface, however your Derived doesn't really derive from your interface, so that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: That only works when the Base is polymorphic (e.g. by having a virtual function). When you are totally sure, a static_cast is ok, but then again you should wonder why your being sure is not expressed in the code as using the type right away. Or by using virtual functions or the visitor pattern.

Comment: He says he knows it's a Derived so he should use `static_cast<Derived>(object)` since it incurs in much less overhead.

Comment: Show us your 'Object' base class, does it have `virtual` functions inside?

Comment: @Tony: Why can't i use Object *obj = new Ball() and cast it to ITouchResponder*? The Ball is ITouchResponder

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways but they don't have the same impact :

```
Derived* derived = static_cast<Derived*>(object);
```

Use this one if you know at compile time that it should be of the correct type. It will not fail at runtime if it's not possible but will at compile time.

```
Derived* derived = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(object);
```

Use this if you're not sure and want the runtime to automatically check if it's possible. If it is you'll get a valid pointer, if not you'll get a nullptr. Know that dynamic_cast<> checks are costly in time performance so a lot of people sometimes use associative containers with type_info pointers as key, where possible, because the check is less costly, but really it depends on the context. To get more infos, look for the typeid keyword.

Now, there is also the C way of doing it but it's not recommanded because it's not clear what exactly will the compiler generated. At least with those previous ways you know exactly how the code should behave. So I'll not describe it.