# how does c++ multiple inheritance casting work?

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417189/c-multiple-inheritance-casting) helped me to understand a bit, but my question is slightly different from theirs.

Basic typecasting as I understand it in c++ involves reinterpreting a structure in memory, as a different structure. For example:

```
class Building{int sqFootage;};

class Office : public Building{int cubicles;};

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    Office *foo = new Office();
    /*The cubicles member appears after the sqFootage member on an Office,
    * so the foo pointer is really just a Building* with some extra
    * information after it.
    */
    Building *bar = (Building*)foo;
    return 0;
};
```

The critical point here is that an Office can be interpreted in memory as a Building without any changes to the structure. This breaks down in the multiple inheritance case:

```
class Animal{bool alive;};

class WaterDweller : public Animal{float swimSpeed;};

class LandDweller : public Animal{float runSpeed;};

class Amphibian : public WaterDweller, public LandDweller{float transitionSpeed};

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    Amphibian *amph = new Amphibian();
    LandDweller *land = (LandDweller*)amph;
    WaterDweller *sea = (WaterDweller*)amph;
}
```

It is not possible to interpret `amph` as both a `LandDweller` and a `WaterDweller` without reorganizing the `Amphibian` structure in memory. **How do those casts work, assuming they have any useful meaning?** If not, Would `static_cast`, `dynamic_cast`, or `reinterpret_cast` be appropriate here?

EDIT: Thank you very much for the answer Sneftel. The [TinyDr link](http://tinydrblog.appspot.com/?p=89001) you provided in one of your comments was very helpful, and the advice to avoid c-style casts is some I will take to heart.

For those that are curious, here are the pointers I got when I tried running this code:

```
land 0x22c8018
sea 0x22c8010
run 0x22c801c
swim 0x22c8014
land alive 0x22c8018
sea alive 0x22c8010
```

You can see here that even though Land and Water Dwellers inherit from the same base class, they include their own copies of it as if the base classes were different. This leads to the Diamond Problem mentioned by Sneftel in his comments.

Comment: You don't need a single cast here (and get used to C++ casts)

Comment: @KonstantinL No RTTI or dynamic_cast is necessary in this code snippet; all the casts are up-casts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the address stored in `land`, you'll notice that it's a higher number than `amph`. That's because, in C++, casts can end up doing pointer arithmetic as part of their internal operation. `Amphibian` has a `WaterDweller` in it, and a `LandDweller` after that. When casting to a base type whose data doesn't start at the beginning of the derived class, the pointer is adjusted to where that base class's data starts.

Incidentaly, take Dieter's advice, and don't use C-style casts in C++ (particularly for pointer types). The behavior of C-style casts in C++ is a mishmash of `static_cast`, `reinterpret_cast`, and `const_cast`, and it's easy to end up doing something different than you intended, without so much as a compiler warning. Best to make the type of casting you're doing explicit.

Comment: I foresaw this as a possible answer, which is why both `LandDweller` and `WaterDweller` inherit from `Animal`. This way it is impossible for both their respective members to be adjacent to the `Animal`'s member `alive`, assuming base class members always appear before subclass members in the structure. In other words, pointer arithmetic will result in one of those casts not including the member data of its base class.

Comment: @longbowrocks, if you don't use virtual inheritance, there are 2 members of `Animal` type.

Comment: @longbowrocks As Nick said, both of their respective members *are* adjacent to `alive`. It's just a different `alive` for each one. And BTW, trying to access `amph->alive` won't compile, because it's ambiguous. Google "dreaded diamond" for more information.

Comment: @Sneftel Alright, so if I don't use virtual inheritance, Nick's comment is correct, and if I do, it's more like your edit? That is to say, LandDweller objects are compiled to have a blank space the size of an int in the middle to make up for the fact that WaterDweller has swimSpeed next to alive?

Comment: @longbowrocks No, not at all. If you use virtual inheritance, there's rather more complicated stuff going on inside, and the bottom line is that neither `LandDweller` nor `WaterDweller` will assume there's an `alive` right before their own members. An extra hidden field is used to tell them where to find the `Animal` members.

Comment: @Sneftel Why do you believe that any kind of casting changes the address of a pointer? That is completely fallacious.

Comment: @Lother it appears Sneftel is correct at least in the case of g++ 4.6.3. Going to run a few more tests, maybe one with virtual inheritance.

Comment: Incidentally, http://tinydrblog.appspot.com/?p=89001 is a pretty decent description of this stuff.

Comment: Interesting. This is really shifting my understanding of c++.

Comment: @Sneftel Well you learn something new every day. It appears that dynamic_cast does indeed change pointers in the MI case above. Note: None of the other casts (including straight-C cast used in the OP will.)

Comment: @longbowrocks Ha! You think this stuff is weird? Look into member function pointers. They're anywhere from 1 to 3 words long (even under the same compiler!), and don't necessarily contain a memory address.

Comment: @Lother `static_cast`, and C-style casts, will also perform pointer adjustment. Actually, one main purpose of `reinterpret_cast` is that it's guaranteed not to adjust the pointer.

Comment: @Sneftel Mind = blown. That is definitely not the way I would expected a C-style cast to work. That seems completely broken to me. When I cast using C-style it's only as a last resort hack to change the interpretation of the data exactly at that memory location to something else.

Comment: @Lother Indeed. I think it was a crappy language decision. Honestly, I think C-style explicit up/downcasts should have been made illegal, period. Too much hidden complexity.